# How do i persist the text i put on TextArea when click on submit (Form) on Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

It disappears, i tried these and didn't work:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="15" cols="50" value="{{ request.form['text'] }}"></textarea>

<textarea name="text" rows="15" cols="50">{{ text }}</textarea>
```

How to deal with it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="15" cols="50">{{ request.form['text'] }}</textarea>
```

Comment: That's how values are specified in textareas with HTML. It doesn't have anything to do with Flask.

Comment: I know, but has something to do with Flask because of the moustaches